# Using Chart.js - Creating Legend for Doughnut Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I've successfully generated a doughnut chart using Chart.js, as well as a legend, but I'd like the corresponding segment of the chart to highlight with a tooltip when I hover over each item in the legend, just like how it does on [this](http://www.chartjs.org/) page

I tried copying over and modifying the code used on that exact page, but I can't get it to work. Advice and help appreciated!!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Chart.js demo</title>
        <script src='Chart.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="race" width="250" height="250" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></canvas>
    <ul class="doughnut-legend">
        <li><span style="background-color:#40af49"></span>African American</li>
        <li><span style="background-color:#ac558a"></span>Other</li>
        <li><span style="background-color:#f05541"></span>Multi-Racial, Not Hispanic</li>
        <li><span style="background-color:#3ac2d0"></span>Hispanic/Latino</li>
        <li><span style="background-color:#faaf3c"></span>Asian</li>
        <li><span style="background-color:#4287b0"></span>White/Caucasian</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    var pieData = [
                {
                    value: 24.8,
                    color: "#40af49",
                    label: "African American"
                },
                {
                    value : 2.9,
                    color : "#ac558a",
                    label: "Other"
                },
                {
                    value : 5.7,
                    color : "#f05541",
                    label: "Multi-Racial, Not Hispanic"
                },
                {
                    value : 19.1,
                    color : "#3ac2d0",
                    label: "Hispanic/Latino"
                },
                {
                    value : 6.5,
                    color : "#faaf3c",
                    label: "Asian"
                },
                {
                    value : 41,
                    color : "#4287b0",
                    label: "White/Caucasian"
                }
            ];

            var race = new Chart(document.getElementById("race").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData, { tooltipTemplate : "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>%", animateRotate: true });
            var legendHolder = document.createElement('div');
        legendHolder.innerHTML = race.generateLegend();
        // Include a html legend template after the module doughnut itself
        helpers.each(legendHolder.firstChild.childNodes, function(legendNode, index){
            helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function(){
                var activeSegment = race.segments[index];
                activeSegment.save();
                race.showTooltip([activeSegment]);
                activeSegment.restore();
            });
        });
        helpers.addEvent(legendHolder.firstChild, 'mouseout', function(){
            race.draw();
        });
        canvas.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(legendHolder.firstChild);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where you are trying to use 'helpers' and 'canvas' you do not have scope for them.

Helpers refers to Chartjs helpers, this can be easily added by creating

```
var helpers = Chart.helpers
```

Canvas refers to you race variables canvas so just add

```
race.chart.canvas.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(legendHolder.firstChild);
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/d07omyao/) is a fiddle with it working

Comment: @user3908735 cool glad i could help, if this issue is solved for you can you mark the question as answered. cheers

Comment: I have a follow-up question.  It looks like the legend 'div' is generated by the script.  But how would I go about editing the properties of that div (i.e. position)?  And what if I want the chart and the legend to live under a larger div block?

Comment: @user3908735 rather than appending the legend to the race canvas parent parent (bit weird) append it to a div of your choosing, you can then style it using css however you want, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/d07omyao/4/